# How to save color scheme in gVim between sessions?

Tags: gvim, colorscheme

I want to select a color scheme in gVim such that it's used always (i. e. if I select color scheme X, close gVim, and start it again, it should start with X as the color scheme, not the default one).

[image: Screenshot]

How can I do it?

Just selecting the color scheme (see menu in the screenshot above) doesn't help.

Comment: I had the same question and the answers are surprising.  Is it just me, or is it bizarre that a gui program doesn't allow saving settings via the gui?  And the gui file menu doesn't even have an item that opens the user's vimrc (at least not one that is easily visible).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Vim, settings are saved across sessions by writing them in an init script called `vimrc`.

On Windows, that `vimrc` is supposed to be at:

```
$HOME\_vimrc
```

or (if HOME is not defined):

```
C:\Users\yourlogin\_vimrc
```

On Unix at:

```
$HOME/.vimrc
```

The installer may or may not have created that file for you, so you'll have to create if it doesn't exist. Do `:echo $HOME` in Vim to know where to create that directory and that file.

To save your colorscheme choice, add this line to your `vimrc`:

```
colorscheme slate
```

See [this document](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc).

Answer (score 1):

If you use gVim, go to Edit -> click on Startup Settings -> add in the file "colorscheme slate" -> save

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) It looks to me that your solution is a duplicate of the one of @romain. Although it brings that the `vimrc` file can edited from the `gVim` menu.  Maybe  could you make that more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux, the `vimrc` file at home directory, so if you want to edit:

```
$ cd ~
$ vi .vimrc
```

and then please, add or edit `colorscheme` line like:
`colorscheme torte`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! `cd` doesn’t mean edit, it means change directory; and this doesn’t make sense on files. Also the vimrc can be located in other places (I prefer `~/.vim/vimrc`).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to this site. While this shows how to edit one's vimrc (in some cases) that doesn't answer the question about changing the colorscheme setting.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @statox ; perhaps you meant to suggest an edit on the other answer to include the location for linux?

Comment: @statox thanks for the suggestion. I added the information for setting.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I still think that adding answer for Linux only is clear than putting confusing information in the answer for Windows

Comment: The only windows-specific part is the location of the vimrc; another alternative would be to [edit] and answer the actual question, which is « how do I keep my preferred colorscheme on in (g)vim? »

Answer (score -2):

In Windows 10 nowadays you have to edit (with admin privileges) the file _vimrc located in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Vim\_vimrc` 
And add the line: 
`colorscheme <colorscheme>`

Font where i found the way to solve this: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_the_color_scheme

Comment: There's no reason to edit the `_vimrc` in the program files directory.  `:e $HOME/_vimrc` and put the colorscheme command there.